# Why the comment can't be set at the second line instead of first line?

Tags: comments

I want to add some comment lines when to edit python file:

```
vim  .vimrc
autocmd BufNewFile *.py exec ":call SetTitle_py()"
func SetTitle_py()
        call append(line("."),   "#!/usr/bin/env python3" )
        call append(line(".")+1, "# -*- coding:utf-8 -*- ")
endfunc
```

The title is set at the second line when to edit a py file with `vim test.py` ,instead of the first line?

[image]

Comment: because you are using `append()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should `:help append()` a list instead of calling `append()` several times and keeping track of the current line and all:

```
let boilerplate = [
    \ "#!/usr/bin/env python3",
    \ "# -*- coding:utf-8 -*- "
    \]
call append(line("."), boilerplate)
```

Second, `append()` adds lines *after* the given line. Since you are on line 1, `line(".")` returns 1 and the text ends up on line 2, as expected. If you want the text to appear on line 1, you will have to do:

```
let boilerplate = [
    \ "#!/usr/bin/env python3",
    \ "# -*- coding:utf-8 -*- "
    \]
call append(0, boilerplate)
```

Third, `:help setline()` might be a more intuitive alternative:

```
let boilerplate = [
    \ "#!/usr/bin/env python3",
    \ "# -*- coding:utf-8 -*- "
    \]
call setline(1, boilerplate)
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution that coexists with the XDG file template mechanism.

#### Part 1: create a file template containing the shebang etc.

File ~/Templates/python.py:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*- 
"""
"""
```

#### Part 2: read from this file

In my vimrc:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.py 0r ~/Templates/python.py
```

This will read the template file when creating a new file. Added benefit is that it allows me to create a new file from template in one of these new fashioned graphical file manager programs, e.g. Right click -> New Document -> python

I extended this for a number of other languages and find it scales well. Each language takes up one dedicated file template and one line of vimrc.